# How to rewrite binary distribution formula so given $p$ is $\le0.5$?

Tags: statistics, binary

I have to calculate a binary distribution. Normally I would use a table in the back of my Statistics textbook or just crunch the numbers on a few (or quite a few) terms from the sum, but the latter is tedious. The table only has sums from $k=0,n$ where $0<p\le0.5$. I have $p=0.7$.

My question is, how can I rewrite the formula so that the $p$ I am working with is less than or equal to $0.5$?  I know the following is true for my problem:

$$P(Y_7\leq \pi_{0.7})=\sum_7^\infty \binom{8}{k}(0.7)^k(0.3)^{8-k}=1 - \sum_0^6 \binom{8}{k}(0.7)^k (0.3)^{8-k}$$

This is NOT hard to solve manually, but I would appreciate, moving forward, a means to convert $p=0.7$ into $p=0.3$ so I can use the table instead of crunching all the terms myself. I have tried several times and I am missing something. Thank you.

Comment: Excuse me--BINARY distribution. Brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

You've mistaken the word "binary" for "binomial".

You have
$$
\sum_{k=7}^8 \binom 8 k (0.7)^k (0.3)^{8-k} = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^6 \binom 8 k (0.7)^k (0.3)^{8-k}
$$
but also
$$
\sum_{k=7}^8 \binom 8 k (0.7)^k (1-0.7)^{8-k} = \sum_{\ell=0}^1 \binom 8 \ell (1-0.3)^{8-\ell} (0.3)^\ell.
$$
If $Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(8,0.7)$ then $8-Y\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(8, 1-0.7).$ That is why the table only goes up to $0.5$.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, this helped. I couldnt remember what to do. Is the index shift 0,1 from 7,8  because l = 8 - k?

Comment: Does the binomial coefficient get stuck at 1, then? That why it isnt shown in the last line?

Comment: Or does it become (8, 8-l) ?

Comment: @user391838 : You have $\ell = 8-k$, so if $k$ is $7$ or $8$ then $\ell$ is  $0$ or $1$. $\qquad$

Comment: @user391838 : Typo: I omitted $\dbinom 8 \ell,$ but now it's there. Note that since $k=8-\ell$, one should have $\dbinom 8 {8-\ell},$ but $\dbinom 8 {8-\ell}$ is the same as $\dbinom 8 \ell. \qquad$